# Contractible space which is not pointed-contractible. At all. Ever. Under any circumstances.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

A space $X$ is contractible if there is a homotopy $G:X\times I\rightarrow X$ with $G_0=id_X$ and $G_1=x_0$ the constant map at some point $x_0\in X$. The space $X$ is said to be pointed-contractible (with respect to $x_0$) if $G$ can be chosen such that $G_t(x_0)=x_0$ for all $t\in I$.

An interesting example comes from the comb space, which, as parametrised [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comb_space), is contractible, and is pointed contractible with respect to the point $(0,0)$, but *is not* pointed contractible with respect to the point $(0,1)$.

A student of mine posed me the following question. I didn't know an answer, so I'll pitch it to you guys.

> Is there a space which is contractible, but not pointed-contractible with respect to any given basepoint?

Comment: I think  Hatcher's  Algebraic Topology ex 4 pg 18 provides an example

Comment: It's a great exercise to show Hatcher's example is contractible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See Hatcher chapter 0, exercise 6. It is an adaptation of the pathology of the comb space.